# yii2 gridview filterSelector doesn't consider unchecked input

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I use GridView in Yii2 framework.

```
'filterSelector' => 'input[name="AccountSearch[field]"]',


<?= Html::checkbox('AccountSearch[field]', $searchModel->field == true, [
        'label' => 'Field', 'value' => 1
]) ?>
```

When I click it first time - it works well. But when I click more times - checkbox stays always checked. And in http request I see that pjax always sends 'field' = 1. Gridview or pjax bug ?

Comment: I think in this particular instance, the filterSelector "forces" the value of checkbox to be submitted, regardless of whether it is checked or not. I eventually gave up, and changed to a dropdown list, which worked right off the bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden input is automatically generated by default.

[link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#booleanInput()-detail)

> uncheck: string, the value associated with the uncheck state of the radio button. If not set, it will take the default value 0. This method will render a hidden input so that if the radio button is not checked and is submitted, the value of this attribute will still be submitted to the server via the hidden input. If you do not want any hidden input, you should explicitly set this option as null